# Another Normal Distribution question I don't get...

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

Book question: If $Z \sim N(0,1)$ and $P(Z<k) = \Phi(k),$ for $k>0$, find $P(|Z|> k)$ in terms of $\Phi(k)$.

I thought this would be straightforwardly just $2(1-\Phi(k))$. But the answer in the back is $2\Phi(k)-1$, which I don't get at all. Surely $2\Phi(k)-1 = P(|Z|< k)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right! Your textbook answer is referred to the complement probability

$$\mathbb{P}[|Z|<k]$$

Comment: Thanks! Please can you have a look at my question here also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3891883/normal-distribution-standard-deviation-given-as-a-percentage

Comment: @AdamRubinson : done and answered there.